# Error al buscar registros por id con friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hago esto en mis funciones edit, update, destroy

```
@post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
if @post.user_id == current_user.id
```

hay alguna forma de optimizar y hacer una sola función , antes lo hacia de esta manera:

```
before_action :set_user_post, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

private
def set_user_post
  @post = current_user.posts.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

Pero agregue la gema friendly_id y lo modifique asi:

```
private
def set_user_post
  @post = current_user.posts.friendly.find(id: params[:id])
end
```

Pero me da error.

Comment: Hola Carlos, bienvenido a S.O. en español. Cuando agregues preguntas, también incluye los errores generados, no solamente que te dio un error. De todas formas creo que el error se genera porque estas usando `find(id: params[:id])` cuando debería ser `find(params[:id])`

Comment: Si, gracias, ese era el error, ya lo solucione.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucion

```
begin
    @post = current_user.posts.friendly.find(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to @post
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

El error se genera porque estas usando `find(id: params[:id])` cuando debería ser `find(params[:id])`.